# Block ping in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

I have deployed my ASP.NET application on Windows Server 2008 R2. Now, I want to block all ping requests to this server without affecting the operation of my ASP.NET application.

Comment: Why do you want to block ping?

Comment: @ShaneMadden: want ping request disable ie(ping from cmd gives no response)

Comment: But why?  What threat do yo believe you are protecting from?

Answer (score 2):

Try running:

```
netsh firewall set icmpsetting 8 disable
```

Comment: The `netsh firewall` context is deprecated in Windows 2008 R2. However, the alternative that the warning message recommends is `netsh advfirewall firewall`, and `netsh advfirewall firewall set icmpsetting 8 disable` does not work, it says that the command was not found. Apparently the new approach is to just make a rule and treat ICMP as just another protocol: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution

Go to **Start** >> **Administrative Tools** >> Windows **Firewall** with Advanced Security >> **Inbound Rules** >> File and Printer Sharing (Echo Request – ICMPv4-IN) >> right click and select **Enable Rule**.

well now my application works fine and from cmd if you try to send ping request to my server  u will not recieve any response.
This is what i need :)